# What is the best way to bulk list items to ebay?

Tags: e-commerce, ebay-api, ebay-sdk, ebay-lms, ebay-net-sdk

I have thousands of items and multiple eBay accounts.

They are mostly variation items with differing prices per color and size variation.

What's the best way to bulk list all the items?

Previously, I had everything listed one at a time, using either the addItem or addVariationItem calls.

But that can't be how large sellers manage things if in my situation.

What is the preferred way, the eBay API of choice, that best accomplishes this task?

Likewise, for updating the price and stock for all SKUs multiple times per day?

Is there a one-shot call or upload way which can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some  Bulky options with eBay APIs, but if you need to make more than 5000 calls per day you need first to build an App and pass eBay verification, and since 1 item means at least 1 call...

Elsewhere you have to use some SaaS services.

If you've already passed such step you can search for what was the LMS services. Actually they've been decommissioned last weekend but there is the new version (that's not working properly but we hope it will do soon). I suggest you to follow the migration procedure. It is not very clear, as all the eBay documentation, but IMHO is the best path.

Comment: What is your opinion of the feed API? could this be another solution?

Comment: Currently this is the ONLY solution